# Why does the height of my image header changes according to the element below?

Tags: html, css

I'm not very sure why does my image header's height automatically changes despite having the css code in place. Here is one of the sample CSS Code for my image header

```
.imagesadmincoldstorage
{
    position:absolute;
    width:50%;
    height:51.6%;
    margin-left:-25%;
    margin-top:-21%;
}
```

I have input the image size as `51.6%`. However, if there's any additional element below, my imageheader becomes longer despite having the same `height:51.6%;` Why is this so. I also added my html code below.

```
<div id="Slideshowall">
<img src="image/s1.jpg" name="slide" class="imagesadmincoldstorage">
</div>
<div id="headerbodyadmin">
</div>
```

I didnt insert any CSS in my element below my image header.

How do i prevent the image header from resizing according to the element below?

Answer (score 1):

It's a pity you didn't manage to recreate your issue in a fiddle and as you don't give enough code, we will have to guess. I am assuming the content you are adding is in the **same container as the image**. or that the parent container also has percentage dimensions and parent of parent also has percentage and ...

What I am guessing:

**Issue 1 :**

Your `imagesadmincoldstorage` is set to `height:51.6%;` so this means 51.6% of the height of it's container. So if you add content to the container that changes it's height, it is normal that the height of the image changes too.

I won't try to find a solution for that because it realy depends on your layout so if you give more details I can try to help you.

**Issue 2 :**

You are using margin to position your image. Despite the issue that I pointed out before (margins in percent are calculated according to parent's dimentions so if you change the dimensions of the parent, the margins of the child change too) **`margin-top` is calculated according to parent's width** [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) so if the width of the parent changes, it will also move the child verticaly.

To prevent that, use :

```
.imagesadmincoldstorage {
    position:absolute;
    width:50%;
    height:51.6%;
    left:-25%;
    top:-21%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `display:inline-block` for display...Also, there is a closing `"` **missing** in `headerbodyadmin` css

This way, it will have its position fixed, irrespective of amount of text below image!

```
.imagesadmincoldstorage
{
    display:inline-block /* added */
    position:absolute;
    width:50%;
    height:51.6%;
    margin-left:-25%;
    margin-top:-21%;
}
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Yfd5/1/)

Comment: Unfortunately, the height of my imageheader still increases when there's additional values in the gridview which is what i refer to as element in the question :/

Comment: can you just update the fiddle i added to show your problem, or is your site live in some url??

Comment: it is live somewhere. but i'm not sure if it's appropriate to give you the url and the account information to take a look at the problem though

Comment: i understand....just give me a working fiddle with a little more layout and css and we are good to go!! :)

Comment: btw...what is this `imageheader` you continuously refer to....its not any where in your markup or css!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use max-height instead of height.